# Finding the difference between 2 equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

Given the following figure and the following variables and parameters, I have been able to come up with the set of differential equation below the image. My question is what is the assumed difference between latently infected T-cells and actively infected T-cells? In the system of equations the latently infected is $\frac{dL}{dt}$ and the actively infected is $\frac{dE}{dt}$.

Variables
$R(t)$: number of susceptible T-cells (number, $ R(t) \geq$ 0).
$L(t)$: number of latently infected T-cells (number, $L(t) \geq 0).$
$E(t)$: number of actively infected T-cells (number, $E(t) \geq 0).$
$V(t)$: amount of virus (number, $V(t) \geq 0).$

Parameters
$\Gamma$: rate of production of susceptible T-cells (number/time, $\Gamma \geq 0).$
$\tau$: fraction of T-cells susceptible to attack by HIV (unitless, $0 \leq \tau \leq 1).$
$\mu$: removal rate of T-cells (1/time, $\mu\geq0$).
$\beta$: rate of T-cell infection (1/number/time, $\beta>0$).
$p$: fraction of infected T-cells that are latently infected (unitless, $1 \geq p \geq 0)$.
$\alpha$: rate that latent T-cells become activated (1/time, $\alpha \geq 0).$
$\delta$: death rate/removal of actively infected T-cells (1/time, $\delta \geq \mu).$
$\pi$: rate that virus is produced by actively infected T-cells (1/time, $\pi >0$).
$\sigma$: rate of virus removal (1/time, $\sigma >0$).

[image]

$$\frac{dR}{dt} = \Gamma \tau - \mu R - \beta VR $$
$$\frac{dL}{dt} = p \beta VR-\mu L - \alpha L$$
$$\frac{dE}{dt} = (1-p)\beta V R+ \alpha L - \delta E - \pi E$$
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \pi E - \sigma V - \beta V R$$

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear if your question relates to the mathematical or the biological aspects of the problem, but if it's the latter, then a *latently* infected cell harbours the virus but is not involved in active viral replication or production, whereas an *actively* infected cell is facilitating the replication and production of new virus particles.

So a susceptible T cell can be infected to become either latently infected or actively infected (that's what those branches with probability $p$ and $1-p$ represent), but only the latter makes new viruses that can infect more susceptible T cells. The latently infected T cells can transform into actively infected T cells (which thereafter start putting out virus particles).

Comment: thanks for your submission, so you wouldn't be able to relate to this mathematically?

Comment: @fr14 What exactly are you looking for? The simple compartment model is pretty clear, actually.

Comment: I see what you are saying as you follow the arrows through the figure, thanks for that, that makes perfect sense!